# Calls function either press enter or hit button

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I would like to call the JavaScript function when I either hit enter or press the button. Also, I want the function to retrieve the value.

Here is my form:

```html
    <form>
      Farm Number:<br>
      <input id="fnumber" type="text" value="" onKeyDown="findfarm2(event)">  
      <input type="button" value="Find Farm" onclick="findfarm();"> 
    </form>
```

And here is my JavaScript function:

```js
function findfarm2(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13){
  cqlfilter = 'Farm =' + document.getElementById('fnumber').value;  
  unregistered.getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS': 'NCSPCTest:Unreported_Names','CQL_FILTER': cqlfilter});  
  alert(cqlfilter)
  }
  }
  
function findfarm() {
  cqlfilter = 'Farm =' + document.getElementById('fnumber').value;  
  unregistered.getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS': 'NCSPCTest:Unreported_Names','CQL_FILTER': cqlfilter});
  alert(cqlfilter)
  }
```

The button is working but the enter function is not. The 'findfarm2' function can pop out an alert but it isn't passing the value to 'updateParams'.

Comment: maybe the key ENTER will only work if the focus is on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your function (**findfarm2**) do not work, because your form is submitting when you press ENTER button (keyCode = 13).

```
<form id="form" active="#">
    <!-- get value (using parameters) -->
    <input id="first" type="text" value="" onkeydown="find(event, this.value)">
    <input id="last" type="button" value="Find Farm" onclick="findfarm();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //  stop form from submitting

        console.log('You need stop form from submitting!')
    });

    function find(e, val) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log('enter')
        }

        var value = document.getElementById('first').value;

        console.log('My value (using getElementById)' , value)
        console.log('My value (using parameters)' , val)
        // resume your code here...
    }
    function findfarm() {
        console.log('Find Farm clicked!');
    }
</script>
```